# Merge, cbind: How to merge better?

Tags: r, merge, cbind

I want to merge multiple vectors to a data frame. There are two variables, `city` and `id` that are going to be used for matching vectors to data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(array(NA, dim =c(10*50, 2)))
names(df)<-c("city", "id")
df[,1]<-rep(1:50, each=10)
df[,2]<-rep(1:10, 50)
```

I created a data frame like this. To this data frame, I want to merge 50 vectors that each corresponds to 50 cities. The problem is that each city only has 6 obs. Each city will have 4 NAs.

To give you an example, city 1 data looks like this:

```
seed(1234) 
cbind(city=1,id=sample(1:10,6),obs=rnorm(6))
```

I have 50 cities data and I want to merge them to one column in df. I have tried the following code:

```
for(i in 1:50){
citydata<-cbind(city=i,id=sample(1:10,6),obs=rnorm(6))   # each city data
df<-merge(df,citydata, by=c("city", "id"), all=TRUE)}    # merge to df
```

But if I run this, the loop will show warnings like this:

```
In merge.data.frame(df, citydata, by = c("city", "id"),  ... :
  column names ‘obs.x’, ‘obs.y’ are duplicated in the result
```

and it will create 50 columns, instead of one long column.

**How can I merge `cbind(city=i,id=sample(1:10,6),obs=rnorm(6))` to `df` in a one nice and long column? It seems both `cbind` and `merge` are not ways to go.**

---

In case there are 50 `citydata` (each has 6 rows), I can `rbind` them as one long data and use `data.table` approach or `expand.gird`+`merge` approach as **Philip** and **Jaap** suggested.

I wonder if I can merge each citydata through a loop one by one, instead of `rbind` them and merge it to `df`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data.table` is good for this:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
> df
     city id
  1:    1  1
  2:    1  2
  3:    1  3
  4:    1  4
  5:    1  5
 ---
496:   50  6
497:   50  7
498:   50  8
499:   50  9
500:   50 10
```

I'm using `CJ` instead of your for loop to make some dummy data. `CJ` cross-joins each column against each value of each other column, so it makes a two-column table with each possible pair of values of `city` and `id`. The `[,obs:=rnorm(.N)]` command adds a third column that draws random values (without recycling them as it would if it were inside the `CJ`)--`.N` means "# rows of this table" in this context.

```
citydata <- CJ(city=1:50,id=1:6)[,obs:=rnorm(.N)]
> citydata
     city id         obs
  1:    1  1  0.19168335
  2:    1  2  0.35753229
  3:    1  3  1.35707865
  4:    1  4  1.91871907
  5:    1  5 -0.56961647
 ---
296:   50  2  0.30592659
297:   50  3 -0.44989646
298:   50  4  0.05359738
299:   50  5 -0.57494269
300:   50  6  0.09565473

setkey(df,city,id)
setkey(citydata,city,id)
```

As these two tables have the same key columns the following looks up rows of `df` by the key columns in `citydata`, then defines `obs` in `df` by looking up the value in `citydata`. Therefore the resulting object is the original `df` but with `obs` defined wherever it was defined in `citydata`:

```
df[citydata,obs:=i.obs]
> df
     city id         obs
  1:    1  1  0.19168335
  2:    1  2  0.35753229
  3:    1  3  1.35707865
  4:    1  4  1.91871907
  5:    1  5 -0.56961647
 ---
496:   50  6  0.09565473
497:   50  7          NA
498:   50  8          NA
499:   50  9          NA
500:   50 10          NA
```

Comment: or evrything in one go: `setDT(df)[CJ(city=1:50,id=1:6)[,obs:=rnorm(.N)], obs:=i.obs, on = c("city","id")][]`

Comment: Nice one. (However I'm also guessing OP has pre-existing real city data, so the creation of the join-table is more for showing off that the merge works rather than something to be a part of the actual solution workflow.)

Comment: Thanx. Looking at the question, I think it is highly probably the `citydata` are the already existing data and the `df` has to be constructed with a `CJ` in order to get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

In base R you can do this with a combination of `expand.grid` and `merge`:

```
citydata <- expand.grid(city=1:50,id=1:6)
citydata$obs <- rnorm(nrow(citydata))

res <- merge(df, citydata, by = c("city","id"), all.x = TRUE)
```

which gives:

```
> head(res,12)
    city id        obs
 1:    1  1 -0.3121133
 2:    1  2 -1.3554576
 3:    1  3 -0.9056468
 4:    1  4 -0.6511869
 5:    1  5 -1.0447499
 6:    1  6  1.5939187
 7:    1  7         NA
 8:    1  8         NA
 9:    1  9         NA
10:    1 10         NA
11:    2  1  0.5423479
12:    2  2 -2.3663335
```

---

A similar approach with *dplyr* and *tidyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

res <- crossing(city=1:50,id=1:6) %>% 
  mutate(obs = rnorm(n())) %>%
  right_join(., df, by = c("city","id"))
```

which gives:

```
> res
Source: local data frame [500 x 3]

    city    id        obs
   (int) (int)      (dbl)
1      1     1 -0.5335660
2      1     2  1.0582001
3      1     3 -1.3888310
4      1     4  1.8519262
5      1     5 -0.9971686
6      1     6  1.3508046
7      1     7         NA
8      1     8         NA
9      1     9         NA
10     1    10         NA
..   ...   ...        ...
```